# Recommended ASP.NET-enabled Windows shared host?

Tags: windows, shared-hosting

I have a client that is vastly overpaying for shared server space considering the deal they have set up, but since they use DotNetNuke and were set up on Windows by the previous IT guy, they have to use a Windows server for now. This sucks because I don't know any good shared Windows hosts. Where can I find good shared Windows hosting at a reasonable price?

Answer (score 0):

1and1 is generally regarded as a pretty cheap and simple host for all platforms. Their Windows packages start at $4/month.

[1 and 1 Windows hosting prices](http://order.1and1.com/xml/order/MsHosting;jsessionid=288C847831EA51CC803EA7D3EFC28ACA.TCpfix142a?__frame=_top&__lf=Static)

Answer (score 0):

WinHost offers only Windows hosting starting at $4.95 a month and we do support DotNetNuke. We offer a knowledge base article on how to install it as well (http://support.winhost.com/KB/a654/how-to-install-dotnetnuke-5x-on-winhost-servers.aspx)